# Mac OS X 10.6 ODBC Drivers

Tags: sql-server, macos, odbc

I'm going crazy trying to find a <strike>FOSS</strike> free (doesn't have to be open source) ODBC driver to connect to an MS SQL Server. While it doesn't strictly have to be free (which is a huge plus, for obvious reasons), the drivers I have found haven't had an easy to find price tag.

Does anyone know of any preferably free, and if not free, then relatively (sub $30, since it's just for the random times I might need it) cheap drivers for ODBC - MS SQL on OS X?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

unixODBC + FreeTDS is one way: http://www.freetds.org/ & http://www.unixodbc.org/

Comment: So, using FreeTDS in conjunction with unixODBC through the iODBC Administrator will let me use pyodbc in Python? It's a bit late; haven't read through how FreeTDS matches up with unixODBC.

Comment: FreeTDS should be usable as a provider w/ pyodbc. This project for instance uses FreeTDS + pyodbc to connect to SQL Server for Django: http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/

Comment: I didn't use the unixODBC, since OS X has iODBC pre-installed, but after fiddling with odbc.ini (and using the right port. dumb me), I got it working. Thanks!

Comment: You can use pymssql directly with freetds and skip the ODBC layer if you want

Answer (score 3):

Here's a random extract from [Microsoft Office support](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/ODBC-drivers-that-are-compatible-with-Excel-for-Mac-9fa6bc7f-d19e-4f7f-9be4-92e85c77d712):

> If you want to import data into Excel for Mac from a database, you must first install compatible Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) drivers — software that Excel can use to access your database server. ODBC drivers that are compatible with Excel for Mac are available from the following third-party vendors:
>
> - [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/)
> - [Actual Technologies](http://www.actualtech.com/)
> - [Simba Technologies](http://www.simba.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [OpenLink Express Driver for SQL Server on Mac OS X](http://download.openlinksw.com/solwiz/view_solution.php?solutions_id=6177&solution_num=2)? *(Registration required.)*

Comment: openlink drivers are now somewhat expensive :-\

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Mdblite on AppStore?

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mdblite/id487704620?ls=1&mt=12